# A more elegant way to write this jQuery?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I've had to break this down into two parts despite it being toggles. This is because I want to make the animation differ for adding and removing classes.

When the active class **is added** I need to UL to wait until the active CSS transition is complete (0.2 seconds) and then fire the jQuery.

When the active class **is removed** I need to fire the UL width animation first and then on completion remove the active class.

Now because of this it feels dirty and cheap. Is there a simple and elegant solution?

```
// toggle filters
$(".filter .toggle").on('click', function () {

    if ($('.toggle').hasClass('active')) {

        $('.filter ul').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 500, function () {
            $('.filter .toggle').toggleClass('active');
        });

    } else {
        $('.filter').find('.toggle').toggleClass('active').end()
            .find('ul').delay(150).animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 500);
    }

});
```

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zX9SJ/) of my dilemma.

Comment: Possibly better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Td95k/11/)

```
if ( !$('.filter ul').is(':animated') && $('.toggle').hasClass('active') ) {

    $('.filter ul').stop().animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 500, function () {
        $('.filter .toggle').toggleClass('active');
    });

} else {
    $('.filter').find('.toggle').toggleClass('active').end()
        .find('ul').animate({width: 'toggle'
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern works for all manner of reversible animation queues on disparate elements:

- Put your sequence into an array of closures.
- Call `reverse` on it if you want it to run backwards.
- `reduce` the array into a JQuery promise chain.

```
$(".filter .toggle").on('click', function () {
  var a = [ function() { return $('.filter .toggle').toggleClass("active"); } , 
            function() { return $('.filter ul').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 500); } ];
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) a.reverse();
  a.reduce(function(p,c){ return p.then(function(){return c().promise();}); }, $.when());
});
```